# Why does thunderbolt to displayport cable result in video with color bleeding?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, displayport, hdmi

I have an ASUS VE278 display, which is cable of handling VGA, DVI, DisplayPort and HDMI. I have an early 2013 model Macbook Pro, with two Thunderbolt ports, and an HDMI port. If I use the HDMI port (going through an HDMI to DVI converter cable), my ASUS display looks great, just like it did on my PC. No issues. However, if I use a "thunderbolt to displayport" adapter cable (such as [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004CAGDUA)) I get color bleeding artifacts on my screen, around contrasting colors, etc.

If I take a screen shot, everything looks fine on the screen shot (when viewed on another monitor or the Macbook's native display).

Here's a photo of the artifacting, while looking at [this artifact test png image](http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2010/310/b/8/artifact_test_by_spigget-d32bgoh.png) :

(it's hard to capture on camera, so forgive me):

[image]

Does driving a display via ThunderBolt always result in this color bleeding? I am ordering a thunderbolt to HDMI cable.. to see if that makes a difference. But what the heck is going on here?

Comment: "When you plug a device into a television, you expect a clean, crisp signal — a mirror of what you see on the screen. Right?", quoted from [this article](https://www.panic.com/blog/the-lightning-digital-av-adapter-surprise/), see Section "Mystery #2". Could it be this is also *your* problem?

Comment: @myhd - well, that's the lightning connector (which is used on the newer iPhones). I didn't think it applied to this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow. So. Apparently OSX is treating my display as if it were a TV, and is only sending YCbCr color space instead of full RGB color space.

Found [this article](http://www.ireckon.net/2013/03/force-rgb-mode-in-mac-os-x-to-fix-the-picture-quality-of-an-external-monitor/) by Robert Pill that indicates the problem, and how to fix it:

**How to force RGB in Mac OS X**

- Download the patch-edid.rb script from the forums thread above and
  put it in your home directory.
- Connect only the external monitor(s) in question (I closed my MacBook
  lid, for example). The script will make override files for any
  connected monitor. Type “ruby patch-edid.rb” in Terminal.
- A new folder will be created in your home directory. Move it into the
  “/System/Library/Displays/Overrides” folder. If Finder tells you that
  you are overwriting an existing folder, consider backing it up first.
  Restart your computer, enjoy your monitor.

  *To undo the changes, either delete the folder you had copied to the
  Overrides folder (if it didn’t already exist) or replace it with the
  folder you had backed up.*

Also, one of his commenters made an improved script, available [here](https://gist.github.com/adaugherity/7435890).

Comment: Thanks for following up. I have migrated the procedure to your answer. In the future, please don't simply provide a link. We like to keep all steps and information within the answer rather than just link off-site.